# How is com.apple.preference.sound.remoteservice involved with microphone access?

Tags: macos, audio, security, microphone

I just noticed that com.apple.preference.sound.remoteservice accessing my microphone on my MBP in macOS 12.6.3 while not running any communication software. Installed ones are currently denied access in preferences as well. Siri isn't activated. I didn't find much about this service googling.

Any suggestions how to look for what could have triggered this access? Or any thoughts what could initiate this? It's not something that've happened much before. If it has unfortunately I don't remember in what context. I suppose step one is finding out what com.apple.preference.sound.remoteservice is supposed to do. If you know this, please share.

I tried to consult the developer documentation and didn't find much about this remoteservice, but I'm a bit unfamiliar navigating the documentation. Logs weren't generating much useful either, so currently at a loss. Any ideas much welcome.